# Facebook App name doesn't show in my post

Tags: facebook

i have a facebook app and i connected all pages that i manage. 
Facebook has already approved me the permission to publish post in my page by app.
When i publish a new post in my page by app, i don't understand why users can't see app name as in this example:
[POST WITH APP NAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IywTc.png)

I don't see app name:
[POST WITHOUT APP NAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLdbu.png)

I've already set in my facebook app, the url of my website and facebook app canvas.

Answer (score 0):

This so-called “App Attribution” is only shown for user posts, not for page posts.

The reasoning behind this is probably that from a user perspective, it might be interesting to know what apps your friends are using, so you can try them out yourself if you liked what was posted through them; for a page however it might not be appropriate to show to the public which app(s) are used on that page to manage content.

Comment: So, there is no way?

Comment: No, there is not.